# Access denied after January 2018 Windows updates

Tags: windows-10, permissions

After a set of recent Windows updates in January 2018, I have started seeing multiple permissions errors when accessing folders. The issues begin approximately 10 minutes after booting the machine. The issues are not isolated to a particular drive or even to local folders - permissions errors pop up on remote directories as well. Generally these issues arise during writes. It appears that Windows will partially delete a directory, but the directory remains until reboot. In other cases, the directory's contents need to be manually deleted through File Explorer and then the directory can be removed normally.

I don't even know where to begin diagnosing a problem like this. It's incredibly difficult to Google because there are so many different variations on permissions errors out there and this is unlike anything I have seen before. Any guidance on how to diagnose or resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide specifics on which folders?  I am asking for a very important reason, so please, edit your question

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your `Windows Defender Security Center` settings.

Comment: @Ramhound It's all folders. Nothing specific.

Comment: I wanted to see your Settings because I believe I know the reason you experienced this problem.  Sounds like you took steps, so now the problem is no longer an issue, which means this is a non-issue

Comment: Did you happen to have a solution for this or just a rebuild?  I'm in the same state, nothing runs because c:\Users\myuser access seems to be totally screwed up.  Tried to reapply permissions with icacls but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further review I ultimately decided that this was due to corrupted install files. My event logs showed that at some point during Windows' repeating update-restart-update cycles, it forced a restart *mid-update* and then essentially broke the entire permissions system.

I'll refrain from commenting further on Microsoft's choices regarding forced updates, forced restarts, forced browser associations, forced Cortana integration, forced advertisements, etc.